# I got this kind of JSON data, how can I extract one-by-one in PHP?

Tags: php, json

The Json

```
data ={
"2":
  {
    "routtype":"Transactional", 
    "credit":40000,
    "validity":"4616",
    "availablecredit":"39457"
  }
}
```

how to extract this data into variable one by one

Comment: you can use json_decode

Comment: add your code here

Answer (score 2):

assuming $json_array as your array.

```
$data = json_decode($json_array); 
foreach($data as $dt){
    $routtype = $dt->routtype;
    $credit = $dt->credit;
    $validity = $dt->validity;
    $availablecredit = $dt->availablecredit;
    echo $routtype;
    echo $credit;
    echo $validity;
    echo $availablecredit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: if its working then close the question by accepting.